# Mysql CASE statement - finding the Percent Fluctuation of a Field

Tags: mysql, case

I have a table like this

```
id   userid      points    points_change     date
1   6      100    0     2014-10-1
2   6      90    -10    2014-10-11
3   6      20    -70    2014-10-15
4   5      50    0     2014-10-16
```

points is number of points.
points change is the change in number of points from last insert

how would I find the users with most fluctuating points for a given date range?

I tried

```
SELECT `userid`, ABS(((SUM(`points_change`))/MAX(`points`))) AS f
            FROM `mytable`
            WHERE `date` BETWEEN $last AND $now 
            GROUP BY `userid`
            HAVING f > 0
            ORDER BY f DESC LIMIT 10
```

The problem here is when SUM(points_change) is negative you can get > 100% fluctuations which should not happen.

Is there a way to do some kind of case statement, so that if SUM(points_change) is negative, it will add the absolute value of points_change to the Max points.

so for example, in the above data, if I were to select data since 2014-10-15 it would give for userid 6, a change of -70/20 = 315% instead of -70/(20+70)=77%

Comment: Please provide sample data and a description of what you mean by "most fluctuating points".  I can think of several ways to measure this concept.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i added some data

Answer (score 1):

A typical statistical measure of "fluctuation" is variance or standard deviation.  You can calculate these directly in MySQL using `variance()` and `std()`:

```
        SELECT userid, std(points_change) as std_points_change
        FROM `mytable`
        WHERE `date` BETWEEN $last AND $now 
        GROUP BY `userid`
        ORDER BY std_points_change DESC
        LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: thanks gordon. I added some data to make it clearer.

Comment: @user813801 . . . Standard deviation seems like a reasonable measure.